# What is "Hadoop" - the definition of Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

It is kind of obvious and we will all agree that we can call `HDFS + YARN + MapReduce` as *Hadoop*. But what happens with different other combinations and other products in the *Hadoop* ecosystem?

Is, for example, `HDFS + YARN + Spark` still *Hadoop*? Is `HBASE` *Hadoop?* I guess we consider `HDFS + YARN + Pig` *Hadoop*, since *Pig* uses *MapReduce.*

Are only the *MapReduce* tools considered *Hadoop*, but anything else run on `HDFS + YARN`(like *Spark*) is *non Hadoop*?

Comment: If you downvote without a comment, without bothering to state your reason, how can I ever learn what I have done wrong and improve the quality of my future posts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with your impression that the *"Hadoop"* term does not have a useful definition. *"We have a Hadoop cluster"* may mean various things.

There is an official answer though at http://hadoop.apache.org/#What+Is+Apache+Hadoop%3F:

> The Apache™ Hadoop® project develops open-source software for
>   reliable, scalable, distributed computing.
>
> The Apache Hadoop software library is a framework that allows for the
>   distributed processing of large data sets across clusters of computers
>   using simple programming models.

So *"Hadoop"* is the name of a project and a software library. Any other usage is ill-defined.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Apache hadoop definition from [Official website](https://hadoop.apache.org/), I would like to highlight that **Hadoop is a framework** and there are many sub-systems in [Hadoop ecosystem](https://hadoopecosystemtable.github.io/)

**Quoting this content from official website so that broken links in future does not cause any issue to this answer.**

The project includes these modules:

*Hadoop Common:* The common utilities that support the other Hadoop modules.

*Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS™):* A distributed file system that provides high-throughput access to application data.

*Hadoop YARN:* A framework for job scheduling and cluster resource management.

*Hadoop MapReduce:* A YARN-based system for parallel processing of large data sets.

More or less,

***Hadoop  = Distributed Storage (HDFS)  + Distributed Processing ( YARN + Map Reduce)***

But these four modules does not cover complete Hadoop Ecosystem. There are many Hadoop related projects and 40+ subsystems in Hadoop Ecosystems.

Other Hadoop-related projects at Apache include:

*Ambari™:* A web-based tool for provisioning, managing, and monitoring Apache Hadoop clusters which includes support for Hadoop HDFS, Hadoop MapReduce, Hive, HCatalog, HBase, ZooKeeper, Oozie, Pig and Sqoop.

*Avro™*: A data serialization system.

*Cassandra™:* A scalable multi-master database with no single points of failure.

*Chukwa™:* A data collection system for managing large distributed systems.

*HBase™:* A scalable, distributed database that supports structured data storage for large tables.

*Hive™:* A data warehouse infrastructure that provides data summarization and ad hoc querying.

*Mahout™:* A Scalable machine learning and data mining library.

*Pig™:* A high-level data-flow language and execution framework for parallel computation.

*Spark™:* A fast and general compute engine for Hadoop data. Spark provides a simple and expressive programming model that supports a wide range of applications, including ETL, machine learning, stream processing, and graph computation.

*Tez™:* A generalized data-flow programming framework, built on Hadoop YARN, which provides a powerful and flexible engine to execute an arbitrary DAG of tasks to process data for both batch and interactive use-cases. Tez is being adopted by Hive™, Pig™ and other frameworks in the Hadoop ecosystem, and also by other commercial software (e.g. ETL tools), to replace Hadoop™ MapReduce as the underlying execution engine.

*ZooKeeper™:* A high-performance coordination service for distributed applications.

***Coming back to your question:***

Just have a look at 40+ sub systems in Hadoop eco system. Every thing you have quoted may not be Hadoop but most them are related to Hadoop.

**Spark** is part of Hadoop ecosystem. But it can neither use **HDFS** nor **YARN**. HDFS data sets can be replaced with **RDD** ( resilient distributed dataset) and can run in **Standalone** mode without **YARN**.

Have a look at this [article](http://aptuz.com/blog/is-apache-spark-going-to-replace-hadoop/) and this [article](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3014440/big-data/five-things-you-need-to-know-about-hadoop-v-apache-spark.html) for Hadoop & Spark comparison.

Spark use cases over Hadoop:

1. Iterative Algorithms in Machine Learning
2. Interactive Data Mining and Data Processing
3. Stream processing
4. Sensor data processing

***Since Spark doesn't have storage system, it have to depend on one of distributed storages where HDFS is one of them.***

Have a look at related SE question:

[Can apache spark run without hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022334/can-apache-spark-run-without-hadoop/34841539#34841539)

Answer (score 1):

The most generally accepted understanding of Hadoop:  HDFS and Map/Reduce and their related processes and tooling.

A related term:  Hadoop ecosystem:  Hive/Pig/Hbase, Zookeeper, Oozie.  Also vendor specific ones such as impala, ambari.

Comment: True, but I have also read that "spark may replace Map/Reduce as Hadoop's computation engine", so a broader definition may also be HDFS and YARN with whatever engine running on YARN.

Comment: YARN is also referred to as Map/Reduce V2 so my definition still holds.

Answer (score 1):

**Why we require a Big Data System?**

1. **STORE** (to store massive amount of data)
2. **PROCESS** (process the data/requests in timely manner)
3. **SCALE** (scale easily as data grows)

There was a big data solution provided by google.

- Google File System: To solve distributed storage.
- Map Reduce: To solve distributed computing.

Google published the research papers. Apache developed open source system similar to developed by Google, it is known as **HADOOP**.

- Similar to Google File system in hadoop is **HDFS**(Hadoop Distributed File System): File system to manage the storage of data.
- **MAP Reduce**: Framework to process data across multiple servers.

Note: In 2013, Apache released HADOOP 2.0
(MapReduce was broken into two components:

1. MapReduce: A framework to define the data processing task.
2. YARN: A framework to run the data processing task.
   )

**HADOOP ECOSYSTEM**

Hadoop was not easy to understand, and it was limited to hard core developer. so to make the usage of hadoop easier. Lots of tools sprung up, which as a whole is known as Hadoop Ecosystem.

**Hadoop Ecosystem contains tools like:**

1. **HIVE**:

   - provides an SQL interface to hadoop.
   - bridge to hadoop for folks who dont have dont have exposure to OOPs in JAVA.
2. **HBASE**:

   - a database management system on top of hadoop.
   - integrates with our app just like a traditional database.
3. **PIG**:

   - DATA Manipulation Language.
   - transforms unstructured data into structured format.
   - query this structured data using interfaces like Hive.
4. **SPARK**:

   - A distributed computing engine used along with Hadoop.
   - Interactive shell to quickly process datasets.
   - has a bunch of built in libraries for machine learning stream processing, graph processing etc.
5. **OOZIE**:

   - tool to schedule workflows on all the hadoop ecosystem technologies.
6. **FLUME/SQOOP**:

   - tools to transfer data between other systems and hadoop.

*This concludes a very high level overview of Hadoop.*

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop is not a stack like LAMP or MEAN stack. Hadoop is a collections of frameworks and tools that work togethor to solve complex big data problems.

It is basically a Project under Apache foundation. Various Subprojects like Mapreduce, Ambari, Sqoop, Spark, Zookeeper, etc togethor makes ,what is called a Hadoop Ecosystem.

Source : https://www.datacloudschool.com/2020/01/introduction-what-is-hadoop.html