# Can apache mahout ALS work without hadoop?

Tags: windows, hadoop, mahout

I tried using ParallelALSFactorizationJob, but it crashes here:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:739)`

Command line help mentions using filesystem, but it seems it wants hadoop. How can I run it on Windows, mahout.cmd file is broken:

`"===============DEPRECATION WARNING==============="
"This script is no longer supported for new drivers as of Mahout 0.10.0"
"Mahout's bash script is supported and if someone wants to contribute a fix for this"
"it would be appreciated."`

So is that possible (ALS + Windows - hadoop)?

Comment: you can import Mahout jars (mahout-core, mahout-math etc.) into your Java app and run it locally. there is a nice tutorial called "Mahout in action" which describes the usage of various Mahout classes

Answer (score 0):

Mahout is a community-driven project and its community is very strong.

> "Apache Mahout is one of the first and most prominent Big Data machine
>   learning platforms. It implements machine learning algorithms on top
>   of distributed processing platforms such as Hadoop and Spark."

-Tiwary, C. (2015). *[Learning Apache Mahout](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783555211)*.

Apache Spark is an open-source, in-memory, general purpose computing system that runs on both Windows and Unix like systems. Instead of Hadoop-like disk-based computation, Spark uses cluster memory to upload all the data into the memory, and this data can be queried repeatedly.

> "As Spark is gaining popularity among data scientists, the Mahout
>   community is also quickly working on making Mahout algorithms function
>   on Spark's execution engine to speed up its calculation 10 to 100
>   times faster. Mahout provides several important building blocks to
>   create recommendations using Spark."

-Gupta, A (2015). *[Learning Apache Mahout Classification](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/learning-apache-mahout-classification)*.

(This last book also provides a step by step guide *Using Mahout's Spark shell* (they don't use Windows and it isn't clear if they use Hadoop or not though). For more information on that topic, see the implementation section at https://mahout.apache.org/users/sparkbindings/play-with-shell.html.)

In addition to this, you can build recommendation engines using Spark such as DataFrames, RDD, Pipelines, and Transforms available in [Spark MLlib](https://spark.apache.org/mllib/) and

> in Spark, (...) the Alternating Least Squares ([ALS](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/ALS.html)) method is used for
>   generating model-based collaborative filtering.

-Gorakala, S. (2016). *[Building Recommendation Engines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1785884859)*.

At this point, there's one question still to answer before answering your question: [can we run Spark without Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022334/can-apache-spark-run-without-hadoop).

So, **yes**, it's possible to use ALS method on Windows using Spark (without Hadoop).