# Spark illegal character in path

Tags: windows, apache-spark

I am trying to start up Spark on my machine. But when I try to launch using spark-shell I get an error that there is an illegal character in the path.

`Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 49: spark://DESKTOP-0N6IMAQ.fios-router.home:61978/C:\classes`

My environment variables are set as

> JAVA_HOME: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_301
>
> HADOOP_HOME: D:\Hadoop\hadoop
>
> SPARK_HOME: D:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2

And in the path I have

> %JAVA_HOME%\bin
>
> %HADOOP_HOME%\bin
>
> %SPARK_HOME%\bin

The whole error message is

```
21/10/21 18:26:03 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.addReplClassLoaderIfNeeded(Executor.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:220)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2690)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:949)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:106)
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:747)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1020)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:568)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:36)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:116)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:567)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:594)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:564)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$quietRun$1(IMain.scala:216)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:206)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietRun(IMain.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$initializeSpark$2(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$initializeSpark$1(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$4(SparkILoop.scala:165)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.$anonfun$mumly$1(ILoop.scala:166)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:206)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.mumly(ILoop.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loopPostInit$1(SparkILoop.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$10(SparkILoop.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.withSuppressedSettings$1(SparkILoop.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.startup$1(SparkILoop.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:955)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 49: spark://DESKTOP-0N6IMAQ.fios-router.home:61978/C:\classes
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2845)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3018)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3102)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3050)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.<init>(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:57)
        ... 70 more
21/10/21 18:26:03 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.org$apache$spark$scheduler$local$LocalSchedulerBackend$$stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.stop(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:927)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:2516)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$stop$12(SparkContext.scala:2086)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1442)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:2086)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:677)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2690)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:949)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:106)
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:747)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1020)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:568)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:36)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:116)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:567)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:594)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:564)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$quietRun$1(IMain.scala:216)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:206)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietRun(IMain.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$initializeSpark$2(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$initializeSpark$1(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$4(SparkILoop.scala:165)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.$anonfun$mumly$1(ILoop.scala:166)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:206)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.mumly(ILoop.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loopPostInit$1(SparkILoop.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$10(SparkILoop.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.withSuppressedSettings$1(SparkILoop.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.startup$1(SparkILoop.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:955)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
21/10/21 18:26:03 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
21/10/21 18:26:03 ERROR Main: Failed to initialize Spark session.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.addReplClassLoaderIfNeeded(Executor.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:220)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2690)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:949)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:106)
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:747)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1020)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:568)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:36)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:116)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:567)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:594)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:564)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$quietRun$1(IMain.scala:216)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:206)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietRun(IMain.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$initializeSpark$2(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$initializeSpark$1(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$4(SparkILoop.scala:165)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.$anonfun$mumly$1(ILoop.scala:166)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:206)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.mumly(ILoop.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loopPostInit$1(SparkILoop.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$10(SparkILoop.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.withSuppressedSettings$1(SparkILoop.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.startup$1(SparkILoop.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:955)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 49: spark://DESKTOP-0N6IMAQ.fios-router.home:61978/C:\classes
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2845)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3018)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3102)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3050)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.<init>(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:57)
        ... 70 more
21/10/21 18:26:03 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread shutdown-hook-0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.stop(Executor.scala:333)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$stopHookReference$1(Executor.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$2(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2019)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$1(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleBlockPusher$.<init>(ShuffleBlockPusher.scala:465)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleBlockPusher$.<clinit>(ShuffleBlockPusher.scala)
        ... 16 more
21/10/21 18:26:03 WARN ShutdownHookManager: ShutdownHook '$anon$2' failed, java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.executeShutdown(ShutdownHookManager.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.stop(Executor.scala:333)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$stopHookReference$1(Executor.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$2(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2019)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$1(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleBlockPusher$.<init>(ShuffleBlockPusher.scala:465)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleBlockPusher$.<clinit>(ShuffleBlockPusher.scala)
        ... 16 more
```

I do not understand why spark is looking at the path there or how to change it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
This is what my core-site.xml file looks like.

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: By the way, it appears you downloaded Spark with Hadoop, so you don't need to have a separate Hadoop version downloaded as well

Comment: Anyways, you should show your `core-site.xml` in the hadoop conf folder. And there seems to be something using your windows "hosts file" that is returning `DESKTOP-0N6IMAQ.fios-router.home` rather than `127.0.0.1`, for example

Comment: What would cause it to not use localhost or 127.0.0.0?

Comment: There's a variable within the spark-submit command like SPARK_DEFAULT_IP, I think that sets up the executor hostname, but something else is adding C:\classes and that obviously shouldn't be there... I never run Spark or Hadoop on Windows, though, always Linux

Comment: I encounter the same error on Windows 10. Everything works when I switch to spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

Answer (score 23):

i have the exact same problem with the exact number of errors.
Although i found something that seems to work for now (if you have any other solutions please feel free cause this one gets tiring)

---

**The Solution:**

Open a spark cluster manually using the command:

1. **spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master**

Your output should be something like the image below :

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lOKO.png**

This means that your UI is set at localhost:8080
and you have opened the master at 192.168.2.4:7077.

So now the only thing thats left to do is open a **2nd** cmd
and execute the command :

2. **spark-shell --master spark://192.168.2.4:7077**

and you are pretty much ready to go. I dont say that this is the best solution so i hope you elight me with a better one.
I hope i helped.

Comment: I think you meant the UI is at localhost:8080.

Comment: @MosheZvi Yes i am sorry, thank you for pointing out!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
It is not the solution but the explanation what causes the bug. If somebody reads who can verify it and help to fix it, it would be nice.

When you try to start the .\spark-shell.cmd the spark will go through whole initialization of the context.

In case that we use [REPL](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/scala-repl.html) as we do. One of the steps is to make a folder for the REPL output in the fileserver. You can see this in the SparkContext.scala:464.

In this process we call a function addDirectory("/classes", path) which returns the uri for the configuration "spark.repl.class.uri" (in your situation spark://DESKTOP-0N6IMAQ.fios-router.home:61978/C:\classes).

The problem is in addDirectory function and behavior in the File class and different environments
(Windows <=> Linux).

(Windows) -> new File("/classes").getCanonicalPath => C:\classes

(Linux) -> new File("/classes").getCanonicalPath => \classes

This happens in org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv:190

The error which you got comes from Uri constructor while building executor but actually because we (program) generated wrong string (configuration) caused by environment.

We can't affect this from outside configuration.

One possible workaround would be to start spark-shell from [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about).
If you do so you should setup JAVA_HOME.

If you do more complex things as starting master and workers as standalone cluster from the scripts you should do some extra settings.

I hope this can help to bring this problem to somebody who can fix it.

My spark version: spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2

Answer (score 2):

2 solutions:

1. run two shell approach given by BubbleBeam, one for setting master another to spawn the session
2. change spark version I encountered this issue in spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2 switched to version 3.0.3 shell works perfectly fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, I fix it by using the lower version 3.1.2 Spark Release. When I type spark-shell everything just loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Download spark version "spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7" it will solve the issue.

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide much information; could you expand on what should be down with this downloaded spark version?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I do as BubbleBeam and it works for me.
I use spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be fixed now in spark 3.2.2 (hadoop 3.2)