# Can't start spark-shell on windows 10 Spark 3.2.0 install

Tags: apache-spark

## Issue

When I try to run `spark-shell` I get a huge message error that you can see here :
https://pastebin.com/8D6RGxUJ

## Install

I used [this tutorial](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-spark-on-windows-10#ftoc-heading-5), but I already have python and java installed. I used `spark 3.2.0` instead.

Config :
Windows 10

- HADOOP_HOME : C:\hadoop
  downloaded from https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-3.2.0/bin
- JAVA_HOME : C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre1.8.0_311
- SPARK_HOME : C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2
- in path :

  - %SPARK_HOME%\bin
  - %HADOOP_HOME%\bin

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have to put *winutils.exe* in the same folder as the *$SPARK_HOME%\bin* folder. I discovered that after starting from scratch and following [this tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/apache-spark-installation-on-windows/)!

Comment: Only moving the winutils.exe didn't work for me, I'll try starting from scratch with your tutorial later, thanks

Answer (score 1):

By following [this answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70159638/7695460), I downgraded from spark 3.2.1 to 3.0.3 and this seems to have solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem with the following configuration:

- **Spark:** spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7
- **Hadoop:** winutils.exe and hadoop.dll (version 2.7.7 for both)
- **JDK:** jdk-18.0.1

And I recommend that you put the environment variables in User, not System