# How to write dataframe on s3 bucket by pyspark but without using Hadoop

Tags: dataframe, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I Want to write a dataframe directly on s3 bucket by pyspark but dont want to use Hadoop any how. Not single word of Hadoop required in python or pyspark code.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

aws_access_key_id = 'ABC'
aws_secret_access_key = 'XYZ'
region_name = 'ap-south-1'
bucket_name = 'integration'
folder_name = 'NGETL-POC'

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('temp1') \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", aws_access_key_id) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", aws_secret_access_key) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", f"s3-{region_name}.amazonaws.com") \
    .getOrCreate()

data1 = [(1, 'abc', 'A', 1), (2, 'pqr', 'B', 2), (3, 'efg', 'C', 4), (5, 'xyz', 'D', 6)]
fileHeadersColumns = ['student_id', 'st_name', 'st_class', 'st_roll_no']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data1, fileHeadersColumns)
df.show()

data2 = [(1, 'Maths', 50), (2, 'English', 60), (1, 'English', 70), (3, 'English', 80), (4, 'English', 40), (2, 'Maths', 60), (3, 'Maths', 70), (4, 'Maths', 80)]
redisColumns = ['student_id', 'subject', 'Marks']
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, redisColumns)
df1.show()

joinedDf = df.join(df1, on="student_id", how="inner")
joinedDf.show()
print("file uploaded on S3")

# Write the DataFrame to S3 as a CSV
output_path = f"s3a://{bucket_name}/{folder_name}/data_1.csv"
joinedDf.write \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("delimiter", ",") \
    .option("quoteAll", "true") \
    .csv(output_path)
print("file uploaded on S3 post")
```

"""here I am using hadoop in config section{config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider},I just only want to write this Dataframe (joinedDf) on s3 bucket without using hadoop.kindly, provide the solution as soon as possible."""

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: what are you trying or have tried? see [this SO QnA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32022334/8279585).

Comment: @cruzlorite : sometimes I wonder is it the language barrier which is holding them back.

Comment: Kindly write the Python code using PySpark. We need to write the DataFrame to an S3 bucket without using Hadoop.

Comment: Language barrier has resolved @cruzlorite.kindly, resolve the issue

Comment: @priyankajuyal did you really put your AWS keys and bucket name into the first post? *consider those keys compromised and get a new secret key ASAP*. as soon as anything gets hold of it, your data will be copied and someone will be using the credentials to launch bitcoin mining VMs. better to own up to IT "i've accidentally shared a key" than to let them work out what happened later.

Answer (score 0):

straighforward.

1. Write a complete replacement for the s3a connector in your language of choice. 1 week, ignoring tests.
2. Spark File Output code does use the hadoop filesystem APIs so you will need hadoop-common on the classpath unless you replace that too. Full specification is [online](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/filesystem/introduction.html), as are the compliance tests. 2-3 weeks to get the tests to work, unless you try to replace spark writer, which will take longer.
3. You also need the code to commit the output in the presence of worker failure, knowing that directory renames are nonatomic and file rename is slow. EMR and S3A committers both use multipart uploads where workers write to final dest, propagate upload info to spark driver which then completes the upload in job commit. see ["a zero rename committer"](https://github.com/steveloughran/zero-rename-committer/releases/download/tag_release_2021-05-17/a_zero_rename_committer.pdf) for details there. 4+ weeks.

Let us know how you get on.

your other option is: write to a shared filesystem and then have spark driver use s3 command line tools to upload after. Again, your homework.

Comment: I  didn't understand how to do it. Here is my code. I have created a CSV file on an S3 bucket using 's3a,' but I can't see the details.
Can you help me with using S3 so that I can read the data inside the file?
getting the error:
get a "Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o5082.csv." when trying to save to csv file.

Comment: sorry, learning how to debug someone else's open source code is a core part of modern open source development. All the s3a code is published in jar files, any of the IDEs will download it. Oh, and the s3a code *is hadoop code*

Comment: Thanks, Steve, for your invaluable assistance. However, I'm still grappling with the same question: the inability to upload a CSV in an S3 bucket ( using S3). Can we conclude that there is no schema in S3 for uploading a CSV? I prefer not to use s3a (Hadoop).Is there any method for uploading csv in S3.

Comment: "I prefer not to use s3a (Hadoop)". well, you either use *our* or reimplement from scratch. your call